# Dynamic SQL Table creation with GO GORM

Tags: mysql, sql, go, go-gorm

I need to create some SQL tables using go package gorm. The structures of these tables are **unknown** until describing data (or direct data) are given. So, I need to create table **with gorm**, **without using struct**.

Is it possible to do that? Or maybe is it possible to create a struct with *reflect* and use it to create the table?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

GORM has package

> migrator
> Migrator has the following function

```
func (m Migrator) CreateTable(values ...interface{}) error
```

It accepts interface for table creation, so you can play with some map and that CreateTable func